# Angular2 routing stops working after a few clicks in IE10

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart, angular2-routing

We're experiencing an issue in IE10, using Angular2(Dart).
Routing stops showing corresponding views after 3-4 clicks.

I found this report in the AngularJS github which seems to describe our problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8869

Is there a solution for this for Angular2?

Here is the test case:
https://github.com/danbilbo/route-example-for-ie10

Comment: Can you please post the code of a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Included a test case.

Comment: I can reproduce in IE10. Sometimes I even had to restart the VM in order to be able to reload the page, because IE became unresponsive. I would create a bug report in the Angular GitHub repo. You have a great repo project.

Comment: Thank you  Günter. It's one of my team mates who created the test case. Could you please provide a link to the bug tracker? I'll file the bug report.

Comment: http://github.com/angular/angular/issues